# SQL Error = -804 (C# with firebird database)

Tags: c#, sql, database, firebird

I am trying to input data from four text boxes into a Firebird database. Every time I click the button that executes the following code, I get an "`SQL Error = -804 Count of read-write columns does not equal count of values.`"
I'm not sure what this error means. The code I have is:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                string ConnectionString = "User ID=sysdba;Password=masterkey;" +
                "Database=localhost:G:\\nael.FDB; " +
                "DataSource=localhost;Charset=NONE;";

                FbConnection addDetailsConnection = new FbConnection(ConnectionString);
                addDetailsConnection.Open();

                FbTransaction addDetailsTransaction =
                              addDetailsConnection.BeginTransaction();

                string SQLCommandText = " INSERT into Invoice_Name Values" +
                                        "('" + textBox1.Text + "',' "
                                             + textBox2.Text + "',' "
                                             + int.Parse(textBox3.Text) + "',' "
                                             + textBox4.Text + "',' "
                                             + "')";

                FbCommand addDetailsCommand = new FbCommand(SQLCommandText,
                          addDetailsConnection, addDetailsTransaction);
                addDetailsCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                addDetailsTransaction.Commit();
                MessageBox.Show(" Details Added");
        }
```

Comment: I suggest that you always specify the columns you want to insert into, and that you use parametrized queries to guard you against SQL injection

Answer (score 2):

I bet one of your `TextBox.Text` values has a comma in it... Otherwise: Did you check to see if you are specifying the right amount of columns?

Basically, the SQL engine is complaining that you gave it a list of parameters and it is trying to fill those into the table `Invoice_Name`, except, it has too many values for the count of columns in that table. Try printing `SQLCommandText` to the output window (`Debug.WriteLine(SQLCommandText)`) and see if that is what you expect it to be...

You should also not be doing it this way... check this post here: [Inserting into DB with parameters safe from SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315945/inserting-into-db-with-parameters-safe-from-sql-injection)

Comment: Stupid mistake. Two extra single quotations added an extra parameter. Thanks for the link. Very helpful.

Comment: ah. i didn't spot that. sorry. still. don't do it like this - it will leave your application vulnerable to sql injection attacks.